# Linkedin rest api to search people with name

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

Is there any LinkedIn Rest API available to search people with first and last name?

I am not able to find anything on their developer website.

I found this url from some other question: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id))?first-name=bill&last-name=gates

But when I am trying to hit this url from APIGee REST console I am getting response as 403 permission denied. I am using oAuth with my LinkedIn account.

I am currently using free account on LinkedIn, is because of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to get Vetted API access from Linkedin in order to do People Search. For more information please look into this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api)

Comment: This link is dead as of August 2021

Answer (score 10):

Linked has closed its API some time ago. See a detailed announcement [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition).

Comment: Can you please let me know which program should i partner? I am looking to create an application where you can search for people connections as well as people who are not my connections. Also want to get updates from them.

Comment: It seems that Vetted API is what you're looking for, have a look at @ManjunathH's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LinkedIn Public Search Results Scraper API](https://serpapi.com/linkedin-search) to achieve this.
Here is an [example](https://serpapi.com/search?engine=linkedin&first_name=Jimmy&last_name=Neutron). Response for a profile found look like this:

```
{
  "id": "jimmy-neutron-b914a91a5",
  "name": "Jimmy Neutron",
  "occupation": "Chief Executive Officer at NASA - National Aeronautics and Space Administration",
  "location": "Houston, TX",
  "last_job": "NASA - National Aeronautics and Space Administration",
  "last_education": "Harvard University",
  "thumbnail": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQE7YG6jwNNy2Q/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1584908070871?e=1620259200&v=beta&t=QJREJQLCsAIaDiQCOZJ6Nu6QoyUPWK8ytJAWU52icRU",
  "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/jimmy-neutron-b914a91a5?trk=people-guest_people_search-card"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Now LinkedIn does not provide search people apis for the reason for data-stealing.
thanks