# How to get Linkedin profile information (as Name, Bio, etc) using API, if i only have an Email?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

How to get Linkedin profile information (as Name, Bio, etc) using API, if i only have an Email?

So there is a thing: i have a bunch of emails, and i want to get information about them. How can i do this, using Linkedin API?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible. Check [Opal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31471109/1373465):

> LinkedIn has closed its API some time ago. See a detailed announcement [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition).