# Accessing people search API under "LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program"

Tags: linkedin-api

Really sorry for posting this question here (since due to some reason I am unable to post this on LinkedIn forums). I need to work on a project wherein I can increase the number of prospective customers for a company. We want to leverage LinkedIn's database for the same. I went through articles and the program that I got interested in was "LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program" and we will be looking forward to using it to create ads for specific audiences. But I am not able to see if I will have access to people search since [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474460/5159284) post says that I will have access to it but I cannot find confirmation on LinkedIn access documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/getting-started#how-do-i-make-api-calls-on-behalf-of-a-linkedin-member). I have two queries: Is it possible to access people search API wherein we can get individuals in a particular demographic region under the "LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program"? If not this program, in general, can we get paid access to the people search API?

PS: Please do not mark this question as irrelevant as asking question on LinkedIn forum is [disabled](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/ask) (cannot click submit button on the given link even after adding all the details to the form).

Comment: can you point to the doc of the endpoint you want to access?

Comment: I need access to people search API of linkedin. The doc is not available publically I guess, all I was able to find was this link https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api.

Answer (score 0):

People Search is not offered by any of LinkedIn's Partner Programs.